# Use PropertyListSerialization to Make a Dictionary in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to make a dictionary with PropertyListSerialization in swift 2. But it constantly gives this error:

```
"can not convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'NSPropertyListReadOptions'
```

My line of code is:

```
 NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {response,data,error in
          if data != nil {
            let datasourceDictionary = try! NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data! ,options:Int(NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.Immutable.rawValue), format: nil)
```

and this:

```
let datasourceDictionary = try! NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data! ,options:Int(NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.Immutable.rawValue), format: nil)
```

and after that I have to loop over the dictionary:

```
for(key, value): (AnyObject, AnyObject) in datasourceDictionary {
          let name = key as? String
          let url = NSURL(string:value as? String ?? "")
          if name != nil && url != nil {
            let photoRecord = PhotoRecord(name:name!, url:url!)
            self.photos.append(photoRecord)
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should unwrap your data object instead of checking it against nil. Also you need to implement do try catch error handling instead of forcing it:

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let datasourceDictionary = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data, options: .MutableContainersAndLeaves, format: nil)
        print(datasourceDictionary)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.code, error.domain)
    }
}
```

Comment: {
    "Big Fella" = "http://www.sxc.hu/pic/m/n/ng/ngould/325616_big_fella.jpg";
    "Camino al volcan" = "http://www.sxc.hu/pic/m/r/ro/rockberto/489892_camino_al_volcan_.jpg";
    Cheetah = "http://www.sxc.hu/pic/m/n/ng/ngould/329660_cheetah_1.jpg";
}
Got this.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to change it to Int:

```
 NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {response,data,error in
          if data != nil {
            let datasourceDictionary = try! NSPropertyListSerialization
                                            .propertyListWithData(data!,
                                                options:NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.Immutable, 
                                                format: nil)
```

and this:

```
let datasourceDictionary = try! NSPropertyListSerialization
                                            .propertyListWithData(data! ,
                                                options:NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.Immutable,
                                                format: nil)
```